# How do I get my "gedit" plugin to work?

Tags: python, gedit, plugins

I'm trying to install a plugin for the gedit text editor that will allow for split pane viewing of files; i.e. I will be able to view multiple files side-by-side (simultaneously).

The plugin came in a Python file, so I went and tried to run it in my terminal, and this was the result:

```
$ python SplitView.py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "SplitView.py", line 8, in <module>
         import gedit
     ImportError: No module named gedit
```

Given the error on the final line, it would seem that I'm missing a "module" named "gedit". All help is greatly appreciated.

---

Extra info:

- I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04
- My default version of Python is 2.7.6
- I'm using GEDit Version 3.10.4

Comment: Can you link to the source of the plugin? Where did you download it?

Comment: @Parto The page it came from is [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PluginsOld), and the actual file download link is [here](http://www.psyguygames.com/SplitView3.0.tar.gz).

Comment: @Nednarb That plugin will most likely not work. You're looking at the plugins page for Gedit 2 while using Gedit 3.10. This is the correct page for your version: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins-v3.8  A complete list of all available plugins per version: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PluginsLists

Comment: @Parto You are definitely correct about that. Unfortunately there is no plugin to do what I want for my version of gedit, so I'm using the info from https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo and https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowToOld to attempt to modify the plugin I found to work for 3.10. Once I get that working, I'll create an answer to this question compiling your info with Timo's and adding what I did to fix the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the plugin in `$HOME/.local/share/gedit/plugins` and after (re)starting Gedit it should be available in Edit=>Preferences=>Plugins

Comment: Hmm... the only `/gedit` directory on my system is in `$HOME/.config`, and there's nothing inside of there other than an "accels" file.

Comment: @Nednarb You can create that directory manually if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you @Timo That works for another plugin I found that's actually correct for my version of gedit.